# Open-Source JQuery Lightbox Not Functioning

Tags: javascript, jquery, lightbox

URL:

http://qualitygameservers.com.gridhosted.co.uk/

I am attempting to install the JQuery lightbox demonstrated here:

https://designshack.net/articles/javascript/create-a-simple-jquery-image-lightbox-gallery/

Console is returning that it is not in fact a function, however my script experience is minimal.

Any ideas what the problem is? Have i missed something basic or is this an issue with the open source code?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you get both the jquery resource and the lightbox code:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://designshack.net/tutorialexamples/lightbox-gallery/js/jquery.lightbox-0.5.min.js">
```

And if you might want to host that jquery.lightbox file on your own site, in case that tutorial page ever gets moved/deleted.

```js
$(function() {
    $('#thumbnails a').lightBox();
});
```

```html
<link href="https://designshack.net/tutorialexamples/lightbox-gallery/css/jquery.lightbox-0.5.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://designshack.net/tutorialexamples/lightbox-gallery/css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://designshack.net/tutorialexamples/lightbox-gallery/js/jquery.lightbox-0.5.min.js"></script>
<div id="thumbnails">
  <a href="https://designshack.net/tutorialexamples/lightbox-gallery/images/photos/01-turntable-illustration-graphic.png"><img src="https://designshack.net/tutorialexamples/lightbox-gallery/images/photos/01-turntable-illustration-graphic-thumbnail.png" /></a>
  <a href="https://designshack.net/tutorialexamples/lightbox-gallery/images/photos/08-extreme-fish-bowl.png"><img src="https://designshack.net/tutorialexamples/lightbox-gallery/images/photos/08-extreme-fish-bowl-thumbnail.png" /></a>
</div>
```

Comment: I believe i have understood that information and have included both the JS and the CSS file from the tutorial, as i have copied here:    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="assets/css/jquery.lightbox-0.5.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/jquery.lightbox-0.5.min.js"></script>